# How to represent in android the forms to insert a new registry of 1 to many relations

Tags: android, android-room

I've working in an learning app with Room and MVVM. It has a 1:N relation. There is no problem to create registries of cardinality 1, but, ¿how to represent the form to take the data for registries of cardinality N?

I mean, in  the N registry, the user must specify one row of the master table. How it's usually presented?

1. I've seen the new form of Spinners: Exposed Dropdown menus... I think that the result is  not very attractive, and requires some boilerplate code for the adapter.
2. Select previously the master item in a list, and go to the insert form from there. For example:

- List with clickable rows of the master table.
- The user selects one row, loading the data in a new screen. This screen would have a button to create a new slave registry.

Is there another better way??